# C# How can i get this program running? Array problem

Tags: c#, arrays, binary-search-tree, traversal

I should get the output of traversal order  InOrder, PreOrder and PostOrder traversals of binary search tree.
i just can't figure out how to run this program using Array.

```
class Node
{
    public int[] item = new int[11];
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public void display()
    {
        Console.Write("[");
        Console.Write(item);
        Console.Write("]");
    }
}

class Tree
{
    public Node root;

    public Tree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public Node Returnroot()
    {
        return root;
    }

    public void Insert(int id)
    {
        Node newnode = new Node();
        newnode.item[11] = id;
        if (root == null)
            root = newnode;
        else
        {
            Node current = root;
            Node parent;
            while (true)
            {
                parent = current;
                if (id < current.item[11])
                {
                    current = current.left;
                        if (current == null)
                        {
                            parent.left = newnode;
                            return;
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current.right;
                    if (current == null)
                    {
                        parent.right = newnode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Inorder(Node Root)
    {
        if (Root != null)
        {
            Inorder(Root.left);
            Console.WriteLine(Root.item[11] + " ");
            Inorder(Root.right);
        }
    }

    public void Preorder(Node Root)
    {
        if (Root != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Root.item[11] + " ");
            Preorder(Root.left);
            Preorder(Root.right);
        }
    }

    public void Postorder(Node Root)
    {
        if (Root != null)
        {
            Postorder(Root.left);
            Postorder(Root.right);
            Console.WriteLine(Root.item[11] + " ");
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tree BST = new Tree();
        BST.Insert(30);
        BST.Insert(35);
        BST.Insert(57);
        BST.Insert(15);
        BST.Insert(63);
        BST.Insert(49);
        BST.Insert(89);
        BST.Insert(77);
        BST.Insert(67);
        BST.Insert(98);
        BST.Insert(91);
        Console.WriteLine("inOrder Traversal :  ");
        BST.Inorder(BST.Returnroot());
        Console.WriteLine("  ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("PreOrder Traversal :  ");
        BST.Preorder(BST.Returnroot());
        Console.WriteLine("  ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("PostOrder Traversal :  ");
        BST.Postorder(BST.Returnroot());
        Console.WriteLine("  ");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

my question is how to run this code by using array, it's very complicated to me i have tried many ways to get this running still isn't running. i usually get an error of array out of bounce. so maybe how i put the array is wrong? how should i declare array  in this program?

Comment: You likely need to debug your program, see where the problem is at, then figure out why you have that problem at that location.

Comment: C# array use 0-based indexing. Which means declaring an array of 11 elements as you have done (`int[] item = new int[11]`), the last element is `item[10]`. `item[11]` is out of bounds

Comment: Im not really sure if i put the array the correct way. that's why i need assistance. so maybe someone could correct me or teach me how to put the array right.

Comment: the problem here is the array. the other code is okay. i just need to put the array on this code.

Comment: `item[11]` (read "*`item`'s **12th** element*") simply doesn't exist. Just replace it with `item[10]` (read "*`item`'s **11th** element*")

Comment: @Rafalon you should post your comment as an answer as it is likely the correct solution.

Comment: item[10] still gets outofbounce. how can i recontruct this code . to get the array right? or maybe some suggestion on where i did it wrong, other than this i don't get any errors on C#.

Comment: try to declare `Node` class instance outside of `Insert` method means this line => `Node newnode = new Node();` outside of  `public void Insert(int id)` method and then you colud add your item like `newnode.item.Add(id);`

Comment: @YengKun Check my answer, I ran it online and didn't get any IndexOutOfRangeException

Answer (score 1):

You have got a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` error in `Tree` class, in `Insert` method (line 39). You're trying to put id in 12th element of `newnode.item` array (`newnode.item[11] = id;`) but `newnode.item` array have only size for 11th elements. If you want to put this id as 11th element then you have to put `newnode.item[10] = id;` because index of array element is counting from 0 to n, not from 1 to n.

You have to change `someArray.item[11]` to `someArray.item[10]` on your all code.

But if you want to put in on `newnode.item[11]` then you have to change in `Node` class from `public int[] item = new int[11];` to `public int[] item = new int[12];`

Comment: Should be added that every `item[11]` in OP's code will lead to the same error

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in my comments, C# arrays are 0-based.
This means that when you declare an array as

```
int[] item = new int[11];
```

its **11th** element is `item[10]`, and `item[11]` is out of bounds.

Replacing all your attemps to reach `item[11]` with `item[10]` leads to:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Node
{
    public int[] item = new int[11];
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public void display()
    {
        Console.Write("[");
        Console.Write(item);
        Console.Write("]");
    }
}

class Tree
{
    public Node root;

    public Tree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public Node Returnroot()
    {
        return root;
    }

    public void Insert(int id)
    {
        Node newnode = new Node();
        newnode.item[10] = id; // HERE (1/5)
        if (root == null)
            root = newnode;
        else
        {
            Node current = root;
            Node parent;
            while (true)
            {
                parent = current;
                if (id < current.item[10]) // HERE (2/5)
                {
                    current = current.left;
                        if (current == null)
                        {
                            parent.left = newnode;
                            return;
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current.right;
                    if (current == null)
                    {
                        parent.right = newnode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Inorder(Node Root)
    {
        if (Root != null)
        {
            Inorder(Root.left);
            Console.WriteLine(Root.item[10] + " "); // HERE (3/5)
            Inorder(Root.right);
        }
    }

    public void Preorder(Node Root)
    {
        if (Root != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Root.item[10] + " "); // HERE (4/5)
            Preorder(Root.left);
            Preorder(Root.right);
        }
    }

    public void Postorder(Node Root)
    {
        if (Root != null)
        {
            Postorder(Root.left);
            Postorder(Root.right);
            Console.WriteLine(Root.item[10] + " "); // HERE (5/5)
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tree BST = new Tree();
        BST.Insert(30);
        BST.Insert(35);
        BST.Insert(57);
        BST.Insert(15);
        BST.Insert(63);
        BST.Insert(49);
        BST.Insert(89);
        BST.Insert(77);
        BST.Insert(67);
        BST.Insert(98);
        BST.Insert(91);
        Console.WriteLine("inOrder Traversal :  ");
        BST.Inorder(BST.Returnroot());
        Console.WriteLine("  ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("PreOrder Traversal :  ");
        BST.Preorder(BST.Returnroot());
        Console.WriteLine("  ");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("PostOrder Traversal :  ");
        BST.Postorder(BST.Returnroot());
        Console.WriteLine("  ");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Leading to the output:

```
inOrder Traversal :  
15 
30 
35 
49 
57 
63 
67 
77 
89 
91 
98 


PreOrder Traversal :  
30 
15 
35 
57 
49 
63 
89 
77 
67 
98 
91 


PostOrder Traversal :  
15 
49 
67 
77 
91 
98 
89 
63 
57 
35 
30
```

There's no exception here.

Comment: I just said that he have to change "someArray.item[11] to someArray.item[10]" and then he will have a correct solution

Comment: @Presto and I pointed out the five occurences, and proved that it doesn't lead to an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Also note that I just followed the advice given by T_Bacon under OP's question. Last but not least, your `someArray` is wrong (`item` ***is*** the array - despite a seemingly bad name choice)

Comment: we're talking about obvious things :D We have this same on us minds :D